# Merge contents of Two Tables on separate server

Tags: c#, sql

We have a data process which runs to finish in `4-5` days, since we got client data every week, so we run this process on two separate server each week,

So one `Week1` it run on `Server1` and on `Week2` it runs on `Server2`, then `Week3` on `Server1` and so on.

I have introduced some new tables on both servers, these tables has a column `WeekNo`. So `Server1` have Odd Week Number data and `Server2` have Even Week Number data.

The situation is, in every week after populating these new tables, I have to merge data on another servers, so `Server1` and `Server2` will always have same data on these new tables after data process.

I want to do these things in C# because there is already loads of things already done in C#, so just update of the existing package and handover the new `EXE` to *dataprocess team*.

I can do the same in SQL Server Script by using Linked Server.

Also I can connect two different servers using two different connections, but I have billions of rows to move across server, so need to run  **`INSERT INTO SELECT * FROM`** query.

Can anyone tell me how can I link servers in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use SSIS to fultil this job

Thanks

Comment: wow the single line of answer got the _accepted answer_ for a question with 15 lines :D +1